# How to return only value of a field in mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, database, nosql

After applying the find operation in mongodb..  i get the following list of documents..

```
  db.users.find(....)
```

i got:

```
 { "text" : "Hey" }
 { "text" : "Hi" }
 { "text" : "Hello" }
 { "text" : "yes" }
```

How can i convert it into

```
 ["Hey","Hi","Hello","yes"].
```

i tried

```
 db.users.find(...).map( function(u) { return "u.text"; } )
```

but it is giving error!

Comment: And in SQL ( as opposed to "noSQL" ) you do that how? This actually is **way** to broad a question to be constructive to anyone here as well as being impossible without post processing in any environment.

Comment: sorry, but i didn't get you.. what are you trying to say

Comment: i tried db.users.find(...).map( function(u) { return "u.text"; } ) but it is giving error!

Comment: And usage such as `map` as you described above is called "post processing". Also you need to learn how to edit your question here rather than supply relevant information in comments.

Comment: so why this command is giving error? and whats the correct method to di it?

Comment: I submitted an answer to explain this properly

Comment: db.users.find(...) returns you a cursor which is a pointer to result set and it's not a real array. At first you need to convert it to array using .toArray() method then you can apply .map().. check my answer for more details :)

Comment: @shashank If you're doing this in the shell it should work ([map](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.map/#cursor.map)).  What does the error say?

Comment: @JohnnyHK : i was using that on try.mongodb.org and there it was giving error.

Comment: Now it's working fine and one thing i would like to ask is --

if we have some array instead of key value.. like : 

db.users.find(...)

and we get this :

{ "do" : [ "A" , "B" ] }

and i want only this --

[ "A" , "B" ].

I used db.twitter.find(...).map( function(doc) { return doc.following }  ) and it gives me :

[ [ "A" , "B" ] ].

How can i get the required thing.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Not sure what you language implementation is but the basic concept is:

```js
var result = []
db.users.find().forEach(function(u) { result.push(u.text) })
```

And the returned value to `result` is:

```js
["Hey","Hi","Hello","yes"]
```

Answer (score 9):

At first     `db.users.find(...).map()` didn't work because `db.users.find(...)` doesn't return you a real array.

So you need to convert to array at first.

```
db.users.find(...).toArray()
```

Then if you apply map() function will work

```
  db.users.find(...).toArray().map( function(u) { return u.text ; } )
```

Another simple trick is using .forEach()

This will do the trick

```
var cursor = db.users.find(...); // returns cursor object which is a pointer to result set

var results = [];
cursor.forEach(
  function(row) {
     results.push(row.text);
  });

results //results will contain the values
```

Answer (score 8):

Another option is simply to use `distinct`:

```
db.users.distinct("first_name");
```

Would return:

```
[
  "John",
  "Jennifer",
  ...
]
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use

```
var u=db.users.find({...},{text:1,_id:0})
while(u.hasNext()){print(u.Next().text);}
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer here is the method `.distinct()` [(docs)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/)

In your case try it like this:

```
db.users.find(....).distinct('text')
```

That will return only the values.

Answer (score 0):

best way is :

```
db.users.distinct("text");


["Hey","Hi","Hello","yes"].
```

You will get further information regargding this topic here : [mongodb distinct](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a look at the other answers that were given before. Your approach is mentioned there already. In order to keep the site clear and make it easy to find answers, we try to avoid double answers.