# Output values without the associated keys Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

when I do the following query

```
db.mycollection.aggregate({$sample: {size: 2}}, {$project: {"_id": 1,"text": 1}})
```

I get the following output

```
  "_id" : "123", "text" : "some writing"
  "_id" : "456", "text" : "some more writing"
```

I am looking for my output to be something like this

```
"123", "some writing"
"456", "some more writing"
```

Question:

Is there a way to output values (`"123"` and `"some writing"`) without the associated keys?  ( `"_id":` and `"text":`)

Comment: You can add `{$replaceRoot:{newRoot:{ $arrayToObject: {"$zip":{"inputs":[["$_id"], ["$text"]] } }}}}` after sample stage to format the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`db.mycollection.aggregate({$sample: {size: 2}},{$project: { myArray: [ "$id", "$text" ]}})`

will do the job

You can read more here: https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#example-project-new-array-fields

**UPDATE 1**: Updated syntax

Comment: I get `...` when I run the code. Maybe there are missing } or ) at the end?

Comment: for sure, try running it from file so code interpreter will point where the syntax error is

Comment: running it from file...sorry, i'm not sure what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is with native MongoDB query syntax not possible. For an example on how to get this done with JavaScript have a look at the following StackOverflow post: [How to return only value of a field in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23676205/how-to-return-only-value-of-a-field-in-mongodb)