# how to get values in mongodb using find

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have this data in my database.

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5c1b34d11aa970061a76aa68"),
        "city" : "Delhi"
```

I tried to get city like this.

```
 db.myCollection.find({_id:ObjectId("5c1b34d11a970061a76aa68")},{_id:0,city:1})
```

I am getting output `{ "city" : "Delhi" }` like this.
but i need only Delhi without quotes and "city". Is it possible.

Comment: Refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23676205/how-to-return-only-value-of-a-field-in-mongodb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `toArray()` and `map()`

```
db.myCollection
    .find({_id:ObjectId("5c1b34d11a970061a76aa68")},{ _id:0, city:1 })
    .toArray()
    .map(function(result){ return result.city;})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db.myCollection.find({_id:ObjectId("5c1b34d11a970061a76aa68")},function(err,result){
 res.render('yourviewpath', {
        response: result
    });

});
in view you can access like tbis as i am using ejs <%=response.result.city=>
```

it will print only city

Comment: I don't want to print. I need to take that result to frontend.