# Mongodb Aggregation convert array of json to array of array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Is this possible:

convert

```
[ { "a": 1, "b": 2}, { "a": 4, "b": 5" } ]
```

To

```
[ [1,2], [4,5] ]
```

I am asking for a possible aggregate operation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Since Mongodb is built on the concept of Json Documents, you might struggle to do this.

If your collection is small and performance isnt a concern, you could use the built in [`foreach`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/) method (or [map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.map/#cursor.map)) to modify each document returned by a `find` query, which could accomplish do what you're after - **but that will run client side for each result**, which will not be very performant. Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23676779/7840778) for an example.

Failing that, you *could* try doing something sneaky with [mapReduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/#dbcmd.mapReduce) but I think it only supports returning key-value pairs.

My guess is that you'd be better off handling this in your own code on the client by fetching the whole query result set in a single operation (in Json format) and then processing the documents to build the array you need.