# How to output a value from array Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I have an array that contains the values: id, uid, level, I need to output the user id with level = 3 how do I do this? Sample code:
`"users": [{"id": 124, "uid": 2, "level": 1}, {"id": 553, "uid": 19, "level": 3}]`

Comment: Do yo mean [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/oM1Td2Jew24)

Comment: @J.F. No, I only need to output the id in numbers

Comment: Can you post an input and output example?

Comment: @J.F. Input: "users": [{"id": 124, "uid": 2, "level": 1}, {"id": 553, "uid": 19, "level": 3}]; Output: 553

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23676205/how-to-return-only-value-of-a-field-in-mongodb/51105774) question.  Mongo returns an object, the best way is to acces value in the lenguage you use.

Comment: @J.F. Not mongodb, mongoose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `mongoose` you can do this using `findOne`:

```
yourModel.findOne({level:3},{id:1}).then(result => {
  console.log("result = ",result.id)
}).catch(e => {
  // error
})
```

Response is `553`

Example how mongo query works [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8VnkCkM29-K). This example output an array but ising `findOne` only one value will be returned, so you can do `response.name` directly and get the value.

Comment: And is it possible to somehow output the value without .then?

Comment: You can use `async/await`. `var result = await yourModel.findOne(...)`